# Javascript - Add Item in the middle of an array inside map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to add an item in a specific index inside an array inside a map function and it's been behaving unexpectedly. Here's the code for it

```
const addItemToLevelTwoArray= (uniqueID, arrayID )=> {
  const reportObject = {
    id:arrayID,
    title:'',
  }
  
  data.map(section=>{
    section.content.map((report, reportIndex)=>{
      if(report.id===uniqueID){
        section.content.splice(reportIndex, 0, reportObject);
      }
      return report;
    })
   return section;
  })
}
```

Here's a working pen - https://codepen.io/raufabr/pen/vYZYgOV?editors=0011

Expected behaviour is that it would insert an object in the specific index, right above the object where the ID matches.

However, it's acting weirdly and sometimes I'm getting 2 items being added instead of one.

Any tip on what I'm doing would be massively appreciated! I know I'm close but I've been stuck on this for a while now and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: You're using `map` incorrectly. If you're not using the array that `map` builds and returns, there's no reason to use it; just use a loop or `forEach`. More in my post [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/). And the great thing about using a loop is you can just...add another entry, since you're the one building the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preface: You're using `map` incorrectly. If you're not using the array that `map` builds and returns, there's no reason to use it; just use a loop or `forEach`. More in my post [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/). And one reason to use an old-fashioned `for` loop is that *you're* in control of iteration, which matters because...

> However, it's acting weirdly and sometimes I'm getting 2 items being added instead of one.

That's because you're inserting into the array being looped by the `map`, so on the next pass, it picks up the entry you're adding.

If you do a simple loop, you can easily avoid that by incrementing the index when you insert, or by looping backward; here's the looping backward approach:

```
const addItemToLevelTwoArray = (uniqueID, arrayID) => {
    const reportObject = {
        id: arrayID,
        title: "",
    };
  
    for (const section of data) {
        for (let reportIndex = section.content.length - 1; reportIndex >= 0; --reportIndex) {
            const report = section.content[reportIndex];
            if (report.id === uniqueID) {
                 section.content.splice(reportIndex, 0, reportObject);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Because we're looping backward, we won't pick up the entry we just added on the next pass.

Since the outer loop doesn't have that problem, I used the more convenient `for-of`.

---

Since you asked about `map`, if you **do** use the array `map` returns, you can do this by returning an array with the two entries, and then calling `flat` on the array `map` builds. (This only works if the array doesn't already contain arrays, because they'll get flattened to.) This is common enough that it's combined in one function: `flatMap`. It's not what I'd do (I'd do a loop), but it's certainly feasible. Sticking with `forEach` and `flatMap` rather than using `for-of` and `for`:

```
const addItemToLevelTwoArray = (uniqueID, arrayID) => {
    const reportObject = {
        id: arrayID,
        title: "",
    }
  
    data.forEach(section => {
        section.content = section.content.flatMap(report => {
            if (report.id === uniqueID) {
                // Return the new one and the old one
                return [reportObject, report];
            }
            // Return just the old one
            return report;
        });
    });
};
```

That assumes it's okay to modify the `section` object. If it isn't, [Alberto Sinigaglia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68896888/157247) shows creating a new replacement object instead, which is handy in some sitautions.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `flatMap`:

```js
const data = [
  {
    content: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "a"
      },{
        id: 3,
        title: "c"
      },
    ]
  }
]

const addItemToLevelTwoArray= (uniqueID, arrayID )=> {
  const reportObject = {
    id:arrayID,
    title:'',
  }
  
  return data.map(section=> {
      return {
        ...section,
        content: section.content.flatMap( report =>
          report.id === uniqueID 
             ? [reportObject, report]
             : report
          )
      }
    }
  )
}
console.log(addItemToLevelTwoArray(3, 2))
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ironically I made this code on a new tab from scratch, but yes, your answer is way more explanatory  than mine, +1 for you from me

Comment: I didn't doubt you did! (Sorry if it seemed like that, i was just celebrating minds thinking alike.) This is a very useful answer (I was glad to be the first to upvote it). :-) So great to see sollid contributions from folks.

Comment: (And you didn't do the silly thing I do, where I write `map` and `flat` and then go "Doh!" and change it. Every darned time... :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ahaha yes so do I, for me it's because I used to use `.flat(Infinity)` and  you can do it with `flatMap`

Answer (score 1):

The following will extend the inner array `.content`without modifying the original array `data`:

```js
const data = [ {id: 0,title:'main',content:[{id:1,title:'Hello'}, 
                                            {id:2,title:"World"}] } ];

const addItemToLevelTwoArray= (uniqueID, arrayID )=> {
  const reportObject = {
    id:arrayID,
    title:'something new!',
  }
  return data.map(d=>(
    {...d, content:d.content.reduce((acc, rep)=>{
      if(rep.id===uniqueID) acc.push(reportObject);
      acc.push(rep)
      return acc;
    },[]) // end of .reduce() 
  })); // end of .map()
}

const res=addItemToLevelTwoArray(1,123);
console.log(res);
```